# Birthday cake candles- hackerrank

Tags: javascript

My code for this problem works on 8/9 test cases. but i cant figure out why it wont work for the last case.

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
    const candleHeights = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (candleHeights[ar[i]]) {
            candleHeights[ar[i]]++;
        } else {
            candleHeights[ar[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    let tallestCandle = 0;
    let candleCount;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(candleHeights)) {
    if (key > tallestCandle){
        tallestCandle = key;
        candleCount = value;
        }
    }
    return candleCount;
}
```

> Problem:
>
> You are in charge of the cake for your niece's birthday and have decided the cake will have one candle for each year of her total age. When she blows out the candles, she’ll only be able to blow out the tallest ones. Your task is to find out how many candles she can successfully blow out.
>
> For example, if your niece is turning  years old, and the cake will have  candles of height , , , , she will be able to blow out  candles successfully, since the tallest candles are of height  and there are  such candles.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the function `birthdayCakeCandles` in the editor below. It must return an integer representing the number of candles she can blow out.
>
> `birthdayCakeCandles` has the following parameter(s):
>
> - `ar`: an array of integers representing candle heights
>     Input Format
>
> The first line contains a single integer, , denoting the number of candles on the cake.
>   The second line contains  space-separated integers, where each integer  describes the height of candle .
>
> Output Format
>
> Return the number of candles that can be blown out on a new line.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4
> 3 2 1 3
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> Explanation
>
> We have one candle of height , one candle of height , and two candles of height . Your niece only blows out the tallest candles, meaning the candles where . Because there are  such candles, we print  on a new line.
>
> [image: constraints]

The test case that fails looks like this:

Input (stdin)

```
100000

1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 10{-truncated-}
```

Expected Output

```
99999
```

All but 1 number in the array is 1000, and one 999.

I'm not sure why this fails, could be the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This was my first try, I thought it is the best because it looks pretty cool, however it failed on some test cases:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(candles) {
  return candles.filter(n => n === Math.max(...candles)).length;
}
```

Then I tried this and it passes on all test cases:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(candles) {
    let max = 0;
    let counter = 0;

    candles.forEach(item => {
        if (item > max) {
            max = item;
            counter = 1;
        } else if (item === max) {
            counter++;
        }
    });
    return counter;
}
```