# Birthday Cake Candles (simple for loop problem) in HackerRank

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

First post here ever. :D

See the problem here that I can't figure out: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/problem.

All but one test passes; the last one continues to fail.

Someone else also asked question but they used a different strategy, however is having the same test case fail: [Birthday cake candles- hackerrank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877620/birthday-cake-candles-hackerrank).

This is my code:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
ar = ar.sort();
let high = [];
for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    if (ar[i] === ar[ar.length -1]){
        high.push(ar[i]);
    }
}
return high.length;
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: @Teemu I'm not sure if I'm following.  If i isn't initialized with 0, then the loop would skip/not begin the first index: ar[0]  Also, why would ar[ar.length - 1] necessarily be undefined, unless the highest integer was undefined?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... I've had a good look at your code, and I'm pretty sure that it is correct!

I'm not sure how hackerrank tests your code, but maybe you need a little more optimization? Stuff like: storing the highest value as a variable so that you don't need to calculate it every iteration... Storing numbers to `high` instead of storing array (since you only need the number of the tallest candles).

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
    ar = ar.sort();
    let highest = ar[ar.length-1] //calculate once only
    let high = 0;
    for(let candle of ar){
        if (candle === highest){
            high ++; //incrementing
        }
    }
    return high;
}

birthdayCakeCandles([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,5,4,1,2]) //2
```

Or by using `indexof` method.

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
    ar = ar.sort();
    let highest = ar[ar.length-1]
    return ar.length - ar.indexOf(highest);
}
birthdayCakeCandles([1,2,3,3,2,1,5,5,6,4,6,4,3,2,2,2,2]) //2
```

---

**Edit:** Oh, wow, I see why some input case doesn't work. Basically, `Array.sort()` function sorts the array **alphabetically**. Meaning that "25" will be considered as larger than "100".

Apparently the best way here is to pass a function to the **sort()** method to handle the items numerically. From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) , use

```
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
})
```

To shorten it, you could use the arrow function.

```
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

So just replace all the `ar.sort()` with `ar.sort((a, b) => a - b)`

Comment: That's weird; I could have sworn that I had tested with numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b), but you're right, that did the trick.  I am not following with regards to what you say here: " Basically, Array.sort() function sorts the array alphabetically. Meaning that "25" will be considered as larger than "100"."  Thanks for the input!